# Information geometry and emerging general relativity in parametric space of univariant Gaussian

Tags: general-relativity, geometry, information

I am working on a problem of information geometry. Using Fisher information metric It is possible to show that Einstein tensor and stress energy tensor can be calculated. When I took univariate Gaussian defined as: $$P(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi\sigma^2)}exp-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$ The metric tensor is found to be $$ds^2= \frac{d\mu^2+2d\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}.$$Which is a very well known result.Considering the Gaussian as a member of the exponential family  I express it as $$ P(x)=exp(\theta^\alpha F_\alpha(X)-\psi(\theta).$$ The Einstein Field equation in the parametric space takes the form,
$$G_{\mu\nu}=\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=kT_{\mu\nu}.$$ When I consider a Lagrangian of the form $$L=exp(k_1 \partial_\mu\psi+k_2\partial_\sigma\psi)$$
$k_1$ and $k_2$ are constant. It gives the correct components of the stress energy tensor which is proportional to the corresponding components of the metric tensor as per the Einstein field equation. At this juncture my question is:
(i) Have I done any conceptual mistake in considering the Lagrangian.
(ii) From the said Lagrangian  can I derive the time evolution equation which will generate the univariate Gaussian.